# List of XSS payloads with automatic Javascript/etc. execution?

Tags: javascript, html, xss, payload

I've been recently dealing alot with XSS and payload creation. Generally, when creating the injection, there are 2 different types of XSS:

- Automatic execution when loaded.
- Execution which requires additional user interaction.

As you can see in the title, I'm looking for a list of payloads/injections, which lead to automatic code (js mainly) execution. To name a few:

```
<script>alert(1)</script> 
<body onload="alert(1)">
<button autofocus onfocus="alert(1)">
.
.
.
```

The scheme used for the payload should be unique. (Naming other elements in the context of autofocus/onfocus attributes like input or textarea would be redundant)
The payload should be supported by at least one of the following Browsers(recent Versions):

Chrome

Firefox

Safari

IE

Comment: Are you looking for ways to perform XSS-attacks or a black list to prevent them? I only will follow up on the latter. The possibilities are not endless, but many and imo it's time wasted to come up with a list of possibilities. It's safer to make sure nobody can add HTML directly to your page. It should always be scrubbed and rebuild by your standards.

Comment: It's for the creation of a hacking challenge. I want to narrow down the number of possibilities in order to make it harder to solve. Regarding your security advice: Thank you, but I'm aware of that! :)

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the following resources:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet
And
http://html5sec.org

Edit: This is a moving target. Adding all the content from html5sec here would make the answer obsolete/wrong within short time. Check the size of that resource to understand why.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17831393)

Comment: The question in this case is asking for a moving target. The answer itself would be obsolete because introduction of new browser features introduces new vectors. I do not believe OWASP will go away any time soon, html5sec is a massive resource maintained by skilled XSS researchers. Copying said content into a stackoverflow answer makes absolutely no sense.